# DataBinding TextBox with an Integer value WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I want to bind the user score to a text box on the windows phone app in silverlight. here is the skeleton of my Game Class

```
public class Game : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _userScore;
    public string UserScore {
        {
            return _userScore.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            _userScore = Convert.ToInt32(value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("UserScore");
        }
    }
public Game()
    {
        UserScore = "0";
    }
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have

```
<TextBlock Margin="28,74,242,386" Name="scoreTextBlock"
Text="SCORE" DataContext="{Binding UserScore}" />
```

and in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Game theGame = new Game();
        DataContext = theGame;
    }
```

**The Question**

When I run the App, the score gets modified correctly but it doesn't display inside the `scoreTextBlock`.
Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to bind to a `string`. You can bind directly to an integer:

```
private int _userScore;
public int UserScore
{
    {
        return _userScore;
    }
    set
    {
        _userScore = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("UserScore");
    }
}
```

And you'd simply set it like this:

```
public Game()
{
    UserScore = 0;
}
```

Then change your `TextBlock` to:

```
<TextBlock Margin="28,74,242,386" Name="scoreTextBlock" Text="{Binding UserScore}" />
```

You've set the `DataContext` on the view, you don't need to do it again. If you want to display the word "Score" you'll have to use a second `TextBlock`.

This *should* work.

Comment: That doesn't work either.
I think I might be missing some step.

Comment: @nikhil - Hmm - you've implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` and set the `DataContext` - two of the most common mistakes. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278072(v=vs.95).aspx for more info on data bindings.

Comment: The text in there remains SCORE only, it hust doesn't show up there.

Comment: @nikhil - I've just realised the problem

Comment: @ChrisF - Yes, its the binding.

Comment: @RitchMelton - I just saw that!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are attempting to bind on this line:

```cs
<TextBlock Margin="28,74,242,386" Name="scoreTextBlock" Text="SCORE" DataContext="{Binding UserScore}"/>
```

but that is is incorrect. The DataContext property should be the instance of the game class, and Text property should be the score. Something like this:

```cs
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="SCORE:"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserScore}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

That code still needs a datacontext, but I'm not sure how you are instantiating and locating the instance, so I declined to add any example code for it.
Keep @ChrisF's comments in mind also.